# Read from input and store comma separated values in Hash

Tags: perl

I have a Perl question like this:
Write a Perl program that will read a series of last names and phone numbers from the given input. The names and numbers should be separated by a comma. Then print the names and numbers alphabetically according to last name.Use hashes.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Let us see your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following perhaps.

```
my %hash;
foreach(<>){ #reads yor args from commandline or input-file
my @arr = split(/\,/); #split at comma, every line
$hash{$arr[0]} = $arr[1]; #assign to hash
}

#print hash here
foreach my $key (sort keys %hash ) #sort and iterate
{
    print "Name: " . $key . " Number: " . $hash{$key} . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Don't split on commas, CSV isn't that simple, use Text::CSV.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to do it :)

```
my %phonebook;

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($name, $phone) = split /,/;
  $phonebook{$name} = $phone;
}

print "$_ => $phonebook{$_}\n" for sort keys %phonebook;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tasks like this are the strength of perl's command line switches. See [perldoc perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun) for more infos!

**Command line input**

```
$ perl -naF',\s*' -lE'$d{$F[0]}=$F[1];END{say"$_: $d{$_}"for sort keys%d}'
Moe, 12345
Pi, 31416
Homer, 54321
```

**Output**

```
Homer: 54321
Moe: 12345
Pi: 31416
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we split on commas (you should use [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org) generally), we can actually create this hash with a simple application of the [map](http://p3rl.org/map) function and the diamond operator ([`<>`](http://p3rl.org/readline)).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %phonebook = map { chomp; split /,/ } <>;
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%phonebook;
```

The last two lines are just to visualize the result, and the upper three should be in all scripts. The meat of the work is done all in the one line.